# Custom dll files in vb

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a desktop overlay and the user needs to make dlls for certain things like applications and boot files. I have got the part where it searches the directory to find the dll file but any ideas if it's possible to use a dll file from a file path. If not does anyone have a way round it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper, valid question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Assembly.LoadFrom Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.7.2).